How to get Excel custom add-in to identify the workbook file?
I have a customised Excel add-in saved as an .xlam file in the User/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Addins folder and it can be loaded upon Excel program start. I'm trying to figure out the logic on the below tasks.

The add-in file has the macro that I need.
I would then open any pre-processed data file(.xlsx) and then click on the customised add-in button in the Ribbon tab to execute the macro.
The macro performs actions on the data file and then return a post-processed file.

I'm have trouble with the part where I set the data file to a workbook variable but can't really define it. The file name will change every day and whenever I call Application.ThisWorkbook it seems to allocate the add-in file to it, not the actual data file.
Any advice is appreciated.
Thanks,

ThisWorkbook is the workbook where the code lives - in your case that's the Addin. If you want to work on the workbook that was just opened and has the focus, use ActiveWorkbook.
